# Relationship between node_access gid, roles and workflow

Tags: 7, workflows, users

If using workflow, what database table.field does the node_access.gid map to? Does it represent a role, does it represent a workflow sid (state id), or something else?

Example:

```
+---------+------+-----------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| nid     | gid  | realm           | grant_view | grant_update | grant_delete |
+---------+------+-----------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1234561 |    4 | workflow_access |          1 |            1 |            1 |
| 1234562 |    5 | workflow_access |          1 |            1 |            1 |
| 1234563 |    6 | workflow_access |          1 |            1 |            1 |
| 1234564 |    7 | workflow_access |          1 |            0 |            0 |
+---------+------+-----------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

EDIT: After @Berdir's excellent response I wrote the query below to analyze the relationship between node_access.gid, workflow_access.rid, and role.rid:

```
# Establish relationship between workflow, roles, gids, etc.
SELECT 
    r.name AS role,
    r.rid AS w_role_rid,
    wa.rid AS and_workflow_access_rid,
    ws.state AS has_access_to_state,
    wa.sid AS with_state_sid,
    IF(ws.status=1,'YES','NO') AS which_is_enabled,
    wa.grant_view, wa.grant_update, wa.grant_delete
FROM workflow_access wa
    LEFT JOIN role r ON wa.rid = r.rid
    LEFT JOIN workflow_states ws ON wa.sid = ws.sid
ORDER BY r.rid, wa.sid
```

If anyone notices any incongruousness with my query please comment so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](http://drupalcode.org/project/workflow.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/workflow_access.module) (the function workflow_access_node_access_records()), it looks to be the rid, which is the role id. Additionally, it is also defined in workflow_access_node_grants(), which returns the gid's for a given user. And that is the role id's for 'workflow_access' and the user id for 'workflow_access_owner'.

There is also a {workflow_access} table, that contains information about which role has which permissions for each workflow state. Based on that, the access grants for each node are then built.

Comment: Would this query then properly establish the relationship between node_access.gid and roles?
`SELECT wa.sid, r.name, wa.rid
FROM workflow_access wa
LEFT JOIN role r on wa.rid = r.rid
ORDER BY r.name, wa.sid`

Comment: Also, what if I said there's a workflow_access.rid with -1? Is this possible at all? Or is it a legitimate rid like the original admin or anon user? That being said, there's no rid in the role table with -1.

Comment: BTW, thanks for your prompt response, it's really good information.

Comment: line 52 of the file you linked: `'realm'        => ($grant->rid == -1) ? 'workflow_access_owner' : 'workflow_access',` So that does means that the rid of -1 does have some legitimate purpose. However it still makes me wonder about the direct relationship between workflow_access.rid and role.rid.

Comment: You're querying the workflow_access table actually there but something like that should work. I am not sure why you'd want to do something like that, workflow_access.module should maintain that information for you. For the other question, I think that a -1 rid means that this is meant for the node owner, according the   code you quoted. So if it is -1, the realm is workflow_access_owner.

Comment: I'm doing the query just to have a deeper and clear understanding of the data relationship.

Comment: re: rid with -1.
The answer is in [line 74, workflow_access_form()](http://drupalcode.org/project/workflow.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/workflow_access.module): `// special -1 role used to represent the node author`.